# Does the Spanish concept of "Institucionalidad" exist in English? If so, what word is used to describe it?

Tags: single-word-requests

In Spanish, there is a concept we call "Institucionalidad" that is described in the following terms:

> Es el conjunto de creencias, ideas, valores, principios,
>   representaciones colectivas, estructuras y relaciones que condicionan
>   las conductas de los integrantes de una sociedad, caracterizándola y
>   estructurándola (Correa, 1999).
>
> (Is a set of beliefs, ideas, values, principles, collective
>   representations, structures and relationships that condition the
>   behavior of society, characterizing and structuring it)

How is this concept called in English? I found "Institutionality", but in rather informal sources, more like a Spanglish term, than a real term used by English speakers

Comment: 'Institutionalization'; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutionalisation

Comment: Any dad ending in Spanish is basically a ity ending in English, except for exceptions: bondad, goodness; maldad, evil or caridad, charity. But, otherwise, it's pretty much; ITY: normality, reality, for instance. Here is a paper on the subject, Institutionality: “Institution” and “Institutions Matter”
 from the German but the English is excellent: http://file.scirp.org/pdf/OJPS_2014012715274525.pdf

Comment: Here's another one: http://www.latinamerica.undp.org/content/rblac/en/home/library/democratic_governance/dialogoconflictoscasoperu.html

Comment: caution: in colloquial American Enlish "institutionalization" is what happens to you when you go crazy and they put you in a mental institution.

Comment: does "institucionalidad" mean "having the quality or properties of being an institution" or "the process of becoming an institution"?

Comment: "Framework" might work in English, if you modified it with the description of what you list as components of the framework--the set of beliefs, ideas, etc.

Comment: What happened to the expectation that single-word requests include a sentence (in English) with a blank standing for the word sought? I actually don't understand what the Spanish word is supposed to mean, but it doesn't sound to me like the suggestions fill the bill.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes...**@satnam has a correct answer in "[Institutionalize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/institutionalize)"
, but @mobileink makes a very good point.

The term institutionalize lines up with the Spanish definition, but when using institutionalization additional context may need to be added because it is more often used in the colloquial sense and could thus be confusing/misunderstood if used without additional context.

[Systematize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/systematize) or [Standardize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/standardize) could also be used, depending on the context or even [Assimilate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assimilate).  However, if you're looking for a like to like word choice, Institutionalize is the word you're looking for.